# How to replace characters contained in a vector with another single character using R

Tags: r, string

I have the following string:

```
x <- "KDDADQHRQDKWKDEHENRFKDEFVDEKKK"
```

What I want to do is to replace character in that string with `?` if they are contained in this vector:

```
repo <- c("R", "H", "K", "D", "E")
```

Resulting in this:

```
???A?QHRQ??W?????N?F???FV?????
```

I also want the `negation` version, meaning replace everything that is NOT in `repo` with `?`.

Resulting in `KDD?D?HR?DK?KDEHE?R?KDE??DEKKK`

How can I achieve that with R?

Comment: `chartr("RHKDE", "?????", x)` / `chartr(paste(repo, collapse = ""), strrep("?", length(repo)), x)`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Is there a way to `negate` that? Meaning replacing everything that is NOT in `repo` with `?`. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It would be trivial to use `setdiff()` to generate a string of the absent letters but I think at this point it would be better to use `gsub()` as below.  `chartr()` is designed for 1-to-1 replacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsub()` with a regex character class:

```r
x <- "KDDADQHRQDKWKDEHENRFKDEFVDEKKK"
repo <- c("R", "H", "K", "D", "E")
regex = paste0("[", paste(repo, collapse=""), "]")
output <- gsub(regex, "?", x)
output

[1] "???A?Q??Q??W?????N?F???FV?????"
```

Comment: @TimBiegelsen thanks. Is there a way to `negate` that?  Meaning replace everything that is NOT in `repo` with `?`. I tried this but failed ` gsub("^[RHKDE]+", "?", x)`

Comment: The `^` caret needs to be _inside_ the character class, i.e. `[^RHKDE]`.  Use: `paste0("[^", paste(repo, collapse=""), "]")`